# Openlayers coordinate grid with text lables

Tags: openlayers, coordinates

Need to display the coordinates in the middle of the cell of grid. I do this grid, but can not to display coordinates. At zoom this coordinates must change and display on the grid (example write on leaflet).
My example in Openlayers
https://jsfiddle.net/andrii555/setmtbsq/
Grid is write on this example, but in leaflet
http://nakarte.tk/#m=7/48.84664/26.58142&l=O/Ng

Comment: Why did not you use the graticule? http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Graticule.html

Comment: Using a graticule I could not change the grid to match the nomenclature.The grid is built correctly only, requires that the cells display coordinates. as in the example written on the leaflet